# Duplicate a file in python

Tags: python, file, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to duplicate a file in python.

Going through shutil, I've only found solutions to copy and move the files but I need to duplicate a file to rename and keep the original.

```
    photos54_TempString = "photos54/thumb-" + artistName + "_54.jpg"
    photos54_NewString = "quickManik_Music/" + songID + "-" + 
    artistName + "_54.jpg"

    copyfile(photos54_TempString, photos54_NewString)
```

Comment: Can you explain how what you want to do is different from "copy"?

Comment: I.e. what about `shutil.copy(photos54_TempString, photos54_NewString)` is incorrect?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but copy doesn't keep the photos54_TempString file. Instead, it moves and renames it to photos54_NewString

Comment: @ManikKhurana No, you've described the behavior of "move". "Copy" is similar, but it keeps the original file intact.

Comment: @ManikKhurana That would be `shutil.move`

Comment: no, that is move. copy duplicates and keeps original

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Here's an example, using the terminal and the Python interpreter:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ touch myfile
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, May 10 2017, 15:05:55) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copyfile('myfile', 'mysecondfile')
'mysecondfile'
>>> 
$ ls my*
myfile  mysecondfile
```

Comment: The comments under my post explain the answer. Since I want to keep the original I have to use shutil.copy() rather than shutil.copyfile()

Comment: @ManikKhurana No, `shutil.copy` and `shutil.copyfile` work the same in that regard. However,  `copy` does also copy the file's permissions, while `copyfile` doesn't. It's `shutil.move` that doesn't keep the original, i.e. it  *moves* the original to a new location.